# Retrieving data from parse.com and showing them

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to retrieve data from parse.com which i have already sent.

I'm using following code to send the data:

```
-(IBAction)msgSend:(id)sender {
    PFObject *appMsg = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"appMsg"];
    appMsg[@"besked"] = msg.text;
    [appMsg saveInBackground];
    msg.text = @"";
}
```

And to get the data I'm trying this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"appMsg"];
    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"*******" block:^(PFObject *appMsg, NSError *error) {
        NSString *besked = appMsg[@"besked"];
        msgRecieved.text = besked;
    }];
```

At last I'm trying to display the data into a textView.

Im not really loading any data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"tempClass"];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    query.limit =10;
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
      if (!error) {
        // Retrive values like below,object id is retrieved by objects.objectId
         NSLog(@"Object values %@",[objects valueForKey:@"columnName"]);
      } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
      }
    }];
```

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done.'

Comment: login in parse.com. Check if your class "appMsg" has any row? if yes then retrive colum values like i give an example ,use class name and column name instead of mine

Comment: This error can occure when you rename some files outside XCode. To solve it you can just remove the files from your project (Right Click - Delete and "Remove Reference") You re-import the files in your project and everything will be ok !

Comment: Thanks man. This worked. How can i then display the arrays? Im getting 100+ arrays and i want to display the recent 10. i tried: NSString *msg = object[@"msg"];
                msgRecieved0/1/2/3.text = besked[0/1/2/3];

Comment: I got the working code in here but now i only need to display the values. Im getting the correct values in NSLog and i have set the limit to 10 queries. How do i like "create" echo out the data in object C? If i would have made this in php i would echo out a div for each string. But i don't know how to do this in Xcode yet. Should i set an UIView/UITextView/UITableView or should i make some sort of "create" function to create new labels with strings? I know I'm neewbie at Objective C but I'm really glad for all your help ! :)

Comment: I'm using the above code (Thank you!) and need to display the values in labels or some kind of view*

Comment: label.tex= [objects valueForKey:@"columnName"];

Comment: mark this answer as answered if you got your answer.

Comment: Thanks again ! Ive inserted the code but now i get the following error: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: how you are creating label?

Comment: let you want to display first object in label text then use labelName.text= [objects[0] valueForKey:@"ColumName"];

Comment: Thank you guys ! Now i got everything working. I know it might have been hard, but I'm very happy about your help !